# How do search engines implement keyword suggestion?

Tags: search, graph, search-engine, google-search

This is a very important programming question (and a popular interview question), yet I wasn't able to find any direct answer on the internet.

All I know is that they are:

- Based on real searches
- Different for different languages and regions
- Censored
- Based on your search history
- Duplicates removed
- Sorted by most relevant and popular

So we're looking at a data structures that are:

- Easily sortable
- Elements are unique
- The word you type in is somehow connected to the suggestions

My first guess would be: it's a graph. 
Another option is an adjacency list. Each element contains a link list of suggestions etc.

Does anyone know it's **really** done?